# Disable editing of TextModel

Tags: pharo, spec-ui

Can I disable editing of Spec TextModel and use it only for display purposes.

Tried sending it `disable`, no noticeable results

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, maybe you found already an answer. But anyway
"enabled:false" works

TextModel new text:'hello';enabled:false;openWithSpec